# Are there any bitcoin or altcoin wallets that provide a "decentralized" 2fa setup?

Tags: wallet, two-factor-authentication

Have there been any decentralized 2fa service built into the blockchain? it can be bitcoin or any altcoin.

Comment: Nope, there's none.

Comment: This makes no sense. You have to prove the validity of your transaction to the chain - the chain can't send you an SMS to verify.